# Apache commons configuration compatibility with PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer

Tags: spring, annotations, apache-commons

I am trying to use apache commons configuration replacing a PropertiesFactoryBean in a spring application.

It seems to me but commons configuration framework is not compatible with PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer nor with @Value annotations.

If you suggest me a solution please note that I have spring configured only with xml.

Thanks,
Mario

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. commons-config is ancient, and wouldn't know an @nnotation from a garden-snail. @Value implies a ton of expensive mechanism involving reflection and inspection of annotation -- if you still need @Value, you might need to reconsider getting rid of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: the previous answer is no longer correct. Commons Configuration is able to interact with the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, see
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_utilities.html#Use_Configuration_in_Spring for details.

Comment: Hi, I checked the link you posted but can't make it work as they are using an "xmlConfiguration" but I'm using a properties file. Any ideas on how to make it work?